# Intellj crashes when Running Unit Tests

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, ide, heap-memory

I am Running Intellj (version Ultimate 2017.1.3) on Windows 7 (64 bit, 8 GB Ram).
I am working on a quite big maven project.

The problem appears when I try to run Unit Test with JUnit.
Whenever I try to run a method marked with @Test (or debug) it works, but the second time I launch a test (any test, even from another class) Intellj stops to work, just freeze.

I tried another Intellj Version (Comunity Edition) and I have the same problem.
I was thinking that the problem could be connected with Vm Options. Currently I don't have any Vm options in my JUnit Configuration.

Has someone experienced this problem before? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So does it crash or freeze?  If the IDE hangs and doesn't respond: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: It's possible that IJ is building your project before running the tests. Is there a _progress bar_ in the lower right corner when launching the test session, or a _spinner_ and a _Building_ (or something similar) on the bottom bar center?

Comment: @Meo It just freeze

Comment: @Morfic Yes, Intellj Build the Project everytime I run a test method. However, I disabled this option in configuration and still the same, it freeze

Comment: Most likely, you have a system level issue caused by the third-party security solution/tool, see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167837 for details. The following tools are known to block external process execution: Avecto Privilege Guard, AppSense Application Control, McAffee Antivirus.